# setOnTouchListener move to View class

Tags: java, android

I have part of code, everything working without error, but I need method handleTouch in View class. I'm looking for solution how to move setOnTouchListener to different class or looking for better solution.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // looking solution from here
    RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);

    myLayout.setOnTouchListener(
            new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent m) {
                    handleTouch(m);
                    return true;
                }
            }
    );


}

void handleTouch(MotionEvent m)
{
    TextView textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewS);
    int pointerCount = m.getPointerCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++)
    {
        int x = (int) m.getX(i);
        int y = (int) m.getY(i);
        int action = m.getActionMasked();
        String arrow = null;

        switch (action)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                if (x > 800 && y > 0)
                {
                    arrow = "right";
                }
                if (x < 500 && y > 0)
                {
                    arrow = "left";
                }
                if (x > 0 && y > 400)
                {
                    arrow = "down";
                }
                if (x > 0 && y < 200)
                {
                    arrow = "up";
                }
                textView3.setText(arrow);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;
        }

    }

}
      // to here
}
```

GraphicsView.java

```
 public class GraphicsView extends View {


    public GraphicsView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
            super(context, attributeSet);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    }

  }
```

Comment: That handleTouch(m); is the user defined method, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the onTouchEvent inside your custom view class, that is GraphicsView in your class.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

About defining that `handleTouch(m);` method, you can define it into your custom view class, you can get the MotionEvent from the overriden onTouchEvent method and return the arrow string as per your need.